# Train deep classification model with different color features

Tags: image-processing, keras, deep-learning, classification, rgb

I have a simple sequential deep model as below, which performs a binary classification. I pass the 3 color channels of my dataset images to the model for training. How can I add grayscale as the 4th channel to my model? What changes do I need to make?

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from PIL import Image
from random import shuffle, choice
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import optimizers

IMAGE_SIZE = 300
epochs_num = 100
batch_size = 64
IMAGE_DIRECTORY = './data'

def label_img(name):
    if name == 'fire': return np.array([1, 0])
    elif name == 'none' : return np.array([0, 1])

def load_data():
    print("Loading images...")
    train_data = []
    directories = next(os.walk(IMAGE_DIRECTORY))[1]

    for dirname in directories:
        print("Loading {0}".format(dirname))
        file_names = next(os.walk(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, dirname)))[2]
        for i in range(len(file_names)):
            image_name = choice(file_names)
            image_path = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, dirname, image_name)
            label = label_img(dirname)
            if "DS_Store" not in image_path:
                img = Image.open(image_path)
                img = img.resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                train_data.append([np.array(img), label])
    shuffle(train_data)
    return train_data

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

    return model

training_data = load_data()
training_images = np.array([i[0] for i in training_data])
training_labels = np.array([i[1] for i in training_data])

print(str(len(training_images)))
# Split the data
training_images, validation_images, training_labels, validation_labels = train_test_split(training_images, training_labels, test_size=0.2, shuffle= True)
print(str(len(training_images)))

print('creating model')
#========================
model = create_model()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

filepath="./checkpoints/model_{epoch:03d}_{accuracy:.4f}_{val_accuracy:.4f}_{val_loss:.7f}.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor=["accuracy"], verbose=1, mode='max', save_weights_only=False)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
datagen.fit(training_images)
train_gen=datagen.flow(training_images, training_labels, batch_size=batch_size)
#validation
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True)
val_datagen.fit(training_images)
val_gen=datagen.flow(validation_images, validation_labels, batch_size=batch_size)
model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=epochs_num, verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont't think that you need to add gray scale and i 'm not sure if you can "add" it as an extra channel. Gray scale image is an image that RGB values are the same on the same pixel. You can train your classifier to classify gray scale images or coloured ones or both (not recommended). But if your raw data is coloured images keep them as they are and use data augmentation if you need more.

Comment: I want to do it for experiments to see how it affects.

Comment: What worked? I don't see a code. Also some sentences in your descriptions are not clear. Can you revise or clarify a bit?